# Why is there an object file in my "Binary and Entitlements" list

Tags: xcode-organizer

When I send my .ipa file to iTunesConnect via Xcode 6.2, there is a compiled object file (MoneyPowerLoveVC.o) listed under "Binary and Entitlements".

It doesn't appear to hurt anything, but it bugs me.  Why is it there?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered such a problem, the problem has been solved, need to find a folder that contains the files in the  "Binary and Entitlements" list, I found this folder repeat in my project, a yellow folder, a blue folder, delete duplicate blue folder，you can solve the problem.